# PDF file custom zoom level

Tags: pdf

i have a task about .PDF files that pdf file should open in browser with custom zoom level of 125% or 150%, i tried many times, but it is not working properly in firefox, as it implements zoom on PDF file but it switch on page#2, i study the adobe's given parameters for PDF file and tried to use them as following in href,

```
"SICS-47.pdf?page=1&zoom=125,0,0"
```

```
"SICS-47.pdf#page=1&zoom=125,0,0"
```

but no success, anyone here can help me please ?
thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The adobe partner reference states on page 5 that this is for IE and Netscape. I'm not sure how old this document is, but you might want to check the Firefox support for this functionality as it could be incomplete.

Reference: [Adobe Partner](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf)

Another thing you could do is modify the PDF content to make sure the document opens properly. Depending on which tool you're using you could use a free library like the Perl API2 library or a paid tool like the Java iText library. Maybe there are command line tools out there that do the same, but I'm not aware of them.